# Aurelia get value conventer results in view

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I would like to get the result of value conventer that filters an array in my view in order to display the number of results found.

```
  <div repeat.for="d of documents|docfilter:query:categories">
    <doc-template d.bind="d"></doc-template>
  </div>
```

I neither want to move this logic to my controller (to keep it clean), nor to add crutches like returning some data from the value controller.

#### What I want:

So, basically I would like something like angular offers:
Like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593018/2044039): 
`ng-repeat="item in filteredItems  = (items | filter:keyword)"`
or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960240/2044039): `ng-repeat="item in items | filter:keyword as filteredItems"`

#### What I get:

Unfortunately, in Aurelia:

`d of filteredDocuments = documents|docfilter:query:categories`

actually means `d of` **filteredDocuments = documents** `|docfilter:query:categories`, and if I add brackets or `as`, it won't run (fails with a parser error).

#### So,

Is there a clean way of getting data out of data-filter **in view**?

Best regards, Alexander

---

#### UPD 1: when I spoke about returning some data from the value controller I meant this:

```
export class DocfilterValueConverter {
  toView(docs, query, categories, objectToPassCount) {
    ...
    objectToPassCount.count = result.length;
    ...
  });
});
```

#### UPD 2. Actually, I was wrong about this: `d of` **filteredDocuments = documents** `|docfilter:query:categories`. It does not solve the issue but what this code does is :

1) `filteredDocuments = documents |docfilter:query:categories` on init
2) `d of filteredDocuments` which is a repeat over the filtered at the very beginning array

Comment: are you looking for suggestions on how to implement the `DocFilterValueConverter`?  I'm unclear on the question

Comment: nevermind- I think I understand- you want a reference to the filtered array of documents.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Yes, actually I'm just looking for some elegant way of doing that, not something ugly as described in UPD1 :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have an outer-element, you can stuff the filtered items into an ad-hoc property like this:

```html
<!-- assign the filtered items to the div's "items" property: -->
<div ref="myDiv" items.bind="documents | docfilter : query : categories">

  <!-- use the filtered items:  -->
  <div repeat.for="d of myDiv.items">
    <doc-template d.bind="d"></doc-template>
  </div>

</div>
```

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for but it will do the job. I'm looking into whether it would be helpfull to add a `let` binding command- something like this: `<div let.foo="some binding expression">`

## Edit

Here's something a bit nicer:
https://gist.run/?id=1847b233d0bfa14e0c6c4df1d7952597

```html
<template>
  <ul with.bind="myArray | filter">
    <li repeat.for="item of $this">${item}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the ``let.foo`` thing is an awesome idea

Comment: added an option using the `with` binding that you might like better

Comment: @JeremyDanyow is there any an alias can be provided for `$this`, like `as` in Knockout?

Comment: what about if I add a item to the array? in my test it didn't update the view https://gist.run/?id=b98ccbb33e0b32c6387d31eb1240d33b

Comment: I've found a way, https://gist.run/?id=67f19cc1fa2394ed01b025ac984f080f