# Aurelia Value Converter, filtering on sub-properties by parsing expression

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to create a generic filter Value Converter to use in a few cases. I would like to be able filter the items in the array by properties on sub objects like this:

`<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation | filter:'settings.where':'top'" >`

I know I'm going to have to parse the `settings.where` expression to get to the value. So far I have cobbled together the following:

```
import {inject, Parser} from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(Parser)
export class FilterValueConverter {
  constructor(parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
  }

  toView(array, property, exp) {    
    let expression = this.parser.parse(property);
    return array.filter((item) => expression.evaluate(...?) === exp);
  }
}
```

The `parse` appears to give me an expression but was the Parser designed to be used outside the core framework? `evaluate` requires a scope and I don't have one of those... I could walk the expression tree and get the result myself but does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had a chance to look at the framework source I was very nearly there. The code below appears to work. Scope simply requires a `bindingContext`:

```
import {inject, Parser} from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(Parser)
export class FilterValueConverter {
  constructor(parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
  }

  toView(array, property, exp) {    
    let expression = this.parser.parse(property);
    return array.filter((item) => expression.evaluate({bindingContext:item}) === exp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a snipped from an [aurelia blog post about value converters](http://eisenbergeffect.bluespire.com/binding-with-value-converters-in-aurelia/):

[image]

Maybe this helps you, with that in mind you should be able to use your example just without quotes:

`<li repeat.for="row of router.navigation | filter:settings.where:'top'" >`

Comment: That example shows how to pass in a single sub-property value to the value converter. I'm trying to pass in a path than can be evaluated for each item in the array and used to filter each of them.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to achieve and how this pathes you want to be evaluated can look like?

Comment: I have a filter value converter like the one in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29163491/106623. It uses `item[property]` to get a value on each item to compare to. This will not work for sub properties `item['settings.where']` as it not valid JavaScript to access `item.settings.where`. The Parser in aurelia can already parse `settings.where` into an expression but I cant evaluate it without a scope.

Comment: @Tim what if you split your string by `.` and then use something like `item[property[0]][property[1]]`?. Does that work for you?

Comment: I could do it manually but it would still be restricted. What if I wanted to use something like `settings[0].where` as the path? The great thing with the existing parser is it can already deal with this...