# How to create filter in Aurelia using repeat for?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am having json array that I am showing in HTML using repeat.for. I want to search matching records using a search text box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array in aurelia view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162022/filter-array-in-aurelia-view)

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a ValueConverter:

```js
data = [{'a': 'lorem'}, {'a' :'Ipsum'}, {'a' :'bla'}, {'a' :'blub'}, {'a' :'meh'}, {'a' :'isu'}];
```

```js
export class FilterValueConverter {
    toView(items, search) {
        if(search === "" || search === undefined) return items;

        return items.filter((item) => item["a"].includes(search));
    }
}
```

This example implies that you just want to search for one property ("a"). But you could also search in several properties and match the result.

With

```
<div repeat.for="element of data | filter: search" >
...
```

This will match case sensitive, you could use `.toLowerCase()` to match not case sensitive.

If you have a great amount of data this could may have performance issues

Answer (score 1):

Like Kabaehr suggested you can achieve this with value converters to apply a filter function to each of the rows in the able. I've got an example of how to do this in this blog post:

http://sean-hunter.io/2015/12/29/searchable-tables-with-aurelia-value-converters/